# Dynamicly Sized Boxes by Weight? (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, dynamic, resize

I am attempting to create a dynamically sized UI map based on weights variable of specific objects.

The area in which I want to draw will always be the same, for example a 400x400 form.

The number of objects that I want to draw is dynamic but usually ranges from 1-10 (with small exceptions above the range).

Each object has a long value for "weight" and a floating point MinDrawPercent variable that accepts values between 0 and 1.

For an example, I have 3 objects with the following properties which i want to be drawn on my form.

```
DrawnObject a = new DrawnObject(Weight:=100,MinDrawPercent:=0.1);
DrawnObject b = new DrawnObject(Weight:=5000,MinDrawPercent:=0.1);
DrawnObject c = new DrawnObject(Weight:=25000,MinDrawPercent:=0.1);
```

the total weight of the objects drawn to the form is 30001. as a result, each control would be drawn as a rectangle that takes up the following percentages of the screen

```
"a" would display as 10% of the total area (because its weight is < its MinDrawPercent)
"b" would want to display as 16.6% of the total area but cant due to the increase in "a" so would display as 11.6% of the form
"c" would want to display as 83.3% of the total area but cant due to the increase in "a" so would display as 78.3% of the form
```

It is important that they are as square as possible...  I would think it would draw something like this:

[image: example]

I am normally pretty good with UI design and resizing controls but have been wracking my brain on how to accomplish this task.

Would anybody be able to help me out?

Comment: If WinForms, look into the TableLayoutPanel.

Comment: Agree with @LarsTech but I haven't been able to develop it in the amount of time I usually spend answering questions here! So good luck, I'd be interested in seeing a solution.